# Response time for urllib in python

Tags: python, urllib

I want to get response time when I use `urllib`. I made below code, but it is more than response time. Can I get the time using `urllib` or have any other method?

```
import urllib
import datetime

def main():
    urllist = [
        "http://google.com",
    ]

    for url in urllist:
        opener = urllib.FancyURLopener({})
        try:
            start = datetime.datetime.now()
            f = opener.open(url)
            end = datetime.datetime.now()
            diff = end - start
            print int(round(diff.microseconds / 1000))
        except IOError, e:
            print 'error', url
        else:
            print f.getcode(), f.geturl()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What is "response time"? Is it time to make dns request, establish tcp connection, send http headers, receive headers, read html page?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I mean, response time is latency time. Also ping time is okay.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Save yourself some hassle and use the [requests](https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content) module. In its responses it provides a [datetime.timedelta](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) field called 'elapsed' that lets you know how long the request took.

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get('http://www.google.com')
>>> print response.elapsed
0:00:01.762032
>>> response.elapsed
datetime.timedelta(0, 1, 762032)
```

Answer (score 6):

I prefer the requests library but was forced to use urllib3. I found that in urllib3, `response.elapsed.total_seconds()` is roughly equivalent to :

```py
import datetime
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

url_string = "http://google.com"
start = datetime.datetime.now()
response = http.request('GET', url_string)
end = datetime.datetime.now()
delta = end - start

elapsed_seconds = round(delta.microseconds * .000001, 6)
print(elapsed_seconds)
```